# failed login with correct credentials set in the admin db - MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization

In my mongodb I have this db Roles assigned to the user "master" in the "admin" db:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.master",
    "user" : "master",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "cars"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if I try to access to mongo from the command line to the "cars" db with:

> mongo 127.0.0.1/cars -u "master" -p

after entering the password I get this error:

> connecting to: 127.0.0.1/cars 2014-11-22T12:23:27.377+0000 Error: 18 {
>   ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at
>   src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210 exception: login failed

If instead I try to access mongo with:

> mongo 127.0.0.1/admin -u "master" -p

As a result I can login.

Why I can not connect directly to the db "cars"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [the `--authenticationDatabase` option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-authenticationdatabase):

```
mongo localhost/cars --authenticationDatabase admin -u master -p
```